# Deeply nested JSON response from third party

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, algorithm, reactive-programming

I'm getting this deeply nested JSON response from an api that I have no control,

What should be the best way to get to "generalDetails" and then find the first true value under security, address, account and mobile?

```
{
    "info_code": "201",
    "info_description": "info description",
    "data": {
        "status": "here goes the status",
        "failure_data": {
            "source": "anySource",
            "details": {
                "data": {
                    "server_response": {
                        "generalDetails": {
                            "security": {
                                "isAccountLocked": "false"
                            },
                            "address": {
                                "isAddresExists": "true"
                            },
                            "account": {
                                "accountExists": "true",
                                "isValidAccount": "true"
                            },
                            "mobile": {
                                "mobileExists": "true"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My request looks like:

```
@Autowired
private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;


String resp = webClientBuilder.build().get().uri(URL)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, build the model, automatic here https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter.

Then read data with the model

```
.bodyToMono(MyData.class)
```

Then decide how you want evaluate the requirement `find the first true value under security, address, account and mobile`.

What means "first" ? JSON has no natural order without indicating explicity (e.g. field "order": 2).

N.B. "true", "false" of the response are Strings, not booleans.

Once you have the model with data, you may do:

```
Object firstTrue(GeneralDetails gd)  {
    // No null checks here
    if ("true".equals(gd.getSecurtity().isLockedAccount())) return gd.getSecurtity();
    if ("true".equals(gd.getAddress().isAddressExists())) return gd.getAddress();
    if ("true".equals(gd.getAccount().isAccountExists()) || "true".equals(gd.getAccount().isAccountValid())) return gd.getAccount();
    if ("true".equals(gd.getMobile().isMobileExists())) return gd.getMobile();

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"info_code\": \"201\"," +
    "    \"info_description\": \"info description\"," +
    "    \"data\": {" +
    "        \"status\": \"here goes the status\"," +
    "        \"failure_data\": {" +
    "            \"source\": \"anySource\"," +
    "            \"details\": {" +
    "                \"data\": {" +
    "                    \"server_response\": {" +
    "                        \"generalDetails\": {" +
    "                            \"security\": {" +
    "                                \"isAccountLocked\": \"false\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            \"address\": {" +
    "                                \"isAddresExists\": \"true\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            \"account\": {" +
    "                                \"accountExists\": \"true\"," +
    "                                \"isValidAccount\": \"true\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            \"mobile\": {" +
    "                                \"mobileExists\": \"true\"" +
    "                            }" +
    "                        }" +
    "                    }" +
    "                }" +
    "            }" +
    "        }" +
    "    }" +
    "}");
```

Query

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "data.failure_data.details.data.server_response" +
    ".generalDetails.**.mergeObjects().assort().[*]");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "isAddresExists" : "true"
}
```

If changed `isAddresExists` and `accountExists` to `false`

```
    "                        \"generalDetails\": {" +
    "                            \"security\": {" +
    "                                \"isAccountLocked\": \"false\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            \"address\": {" +
    "                                \"isAddresExists\": \"false\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            \"account\": {" +
    "                                \"accountExists\": \"false\"," +
    "                                \"isValidAccount\": \"true\"" +
    "                            }," +
    "                            \"mobile\": {" +
    "                                \"mobileExists\": \"true\"" +
    "                            }" +
    "                        }" +
```

Output

```
{
  "isValidAccount" : "true"
}
```

If you only want the key name

```
String firstTureKey = josson.getString(
    "data.failure_data.details.data.server_response" +
    ".generalDetails.**.mergeObjects().assort().[*].keys().[0]");
System.out.println(firstTureKey);
```

Output

```
isValidAccount
```